# HOW TO GENERATE THE Sequence of formating numbers UNDER THE 'sec/title' ELEMENT BASED ON 'sec/@disp-level' value

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

**Here we are generating the sequence of numbers under the title element based on the 'sec/@disp-level' below are the defined level formating (*Anyone can help me*):**

- @disp-level='1' = I., II., III. etc.
- @disp-level='2' =  A., B., C. etc.
- @disp-level='3' =  1., 2., 3. etc.
- @disp-level='4' = a., b., c. etc.
- @disp-level='5' = (1), (2), (3) etc.

**Example : In this example roman nos. need to be continued.**

**I.**  WHEN PROCEEDINGS MAY BE INITIATED

**III.**    JURISDICTION AND VENUE

**Note - We are sequenceing under the each section.**

**INPUT XML:**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<sec id="ceb_750004516689gl" disp-level="1" specific-use="15.1">
    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.1</named-content>  I.  WHEN PROCEEDINGS MAY BE INITIATED</title>
    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>        
</sec>
<sec id="ceb_1889931838483us" disp-level="1">
    <title>III. JURISDICTION AND VENUE</title>
    <sec id="ceb_623954004359ua" disp-level="2">
        <title>A.   Trusts Under Continuing Court Jurisdiction</title>
        <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
    </sec>
    <sec id="ceb_9159513279045ff" disp-level="2">
        <title>A.   Pursuit of Claims</title>
        <sec id="ceb_791030056239at" disp-level="3" specific-use="15.2">
            <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.2</named-content>  1.  Supervised Versus Unsupervised Trusts</title>
            <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
        </sec>
        <sec id="ceb_825038660717of" disp-level="3" specific-use="15.3">
            <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3</named-content>  3.  Removal From Continuing Court Jurisdiction</title>
            <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
            <sec id="ceb_2491751884245sa" disp-level="4" specific-use="15.3A" sec-type="A">
                <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3A</named-content> a.  Mandatory Removal for Trust With Corporate Trustee</title>
                <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
            </sec>
            <sec id="ceb_655906801656qm" disp-level="4" specific-use="15.3B" sec-type="B">
                <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3B</named-content> 2.  Discretionary Removal for Trust With Individual Trustee</title>
                <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                <sec id="ceb_113027963776kc" disp-level="5" specific-use="15.35">
                    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.35</named-content> (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries</title>
                    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                </sec>
                <sec id="ceb_113027963776kc" disp-level="5" specific-use="15.35A" sec-type="A">
                    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.35A</named-content>    (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries (Added Section 5)</title>
                    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                </sec>
            </sec>
        </sec>
    </sec>
</sec>
<sec id="ceb_541077295354wt" disp-level="1">
    <title>VI.  LITIGATION INVOLVING TRUSTEE AND THIRD PARTIES</title>
    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
</sec>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<sec id="ceb_750004516689gl" disp-level="1" specific-use="15.1">
    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.1</named-content>  I.  WHEN PROCEEDINGS MAY BE INITIATED</title>
    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>        
</sec>
<sec id="ceb_1889931838483us" disp-level="1">
    <title>II.  JURISDICTION AND VENUE</title>
    <sec id="ceb_623954004359ua" disp-level="2">
        <title>A.   Trusts Under Continuing Court Jurisdiction</title>
        <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
    </sec>
    <sec id="ceb_9159513279045ff" disp-level="2">
        <title>B.   Pursuit of Claims</title>
        <sec id="ceb_791030056239at" disp-level="3" specific-use="15.2">
            <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.2</named-content>  1.  Supervised Versus Unsupervised Trusts</title>
            <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
        </sec>
        <sec id="ceb_825038660717of" disp-level="3" specific-use="15.3">
            <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3</named-content>  2.  Removal From Continuing Court Jurisdiction</title>
            <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
            <sec id="ceb_2491751884245sa" disp-level="4" specific-use="15.3A" sec-type="A">
                <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3A</named-content> a.  Mandatory Removal for Trust With Corporate Trustee</title>
                <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
            </sec>
            <sec id="ceb_655906801656qm" disp-level="4" specific-use="15.3B" sec-type="B">
                <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.3B</named-content> b.  Discretionary Removal for Trust With Individual Trustee</title>
                <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                <sec id="ceb_113027963776kc" disp-level="5" specific-use="15.35">
                    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.35</named-content> (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries</title>
                    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                </sec>
                <sec id="ceb_113027963776kc" disp-level="5" specific-use="15.35A" sec-type="A">
                    <title><named-content content-type="none">&#x00a7;15.35A</named-content>    (2) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries (Added Section 5)</title>
                    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
                </sec>
            </sec>
        </sec>
    </sec>
</sec>
<sec id="ceb_541077295354wt" disp-level="1">
    <title>III. LITIGATION INVOLVING TRUSTEE AND THIRD PARTIES</title>
    <p content-type="new">In the course of administering a trustee or beneficiary, <italic>e.g.,</italic> to seek advance court approval of a proposed action.</p>
</sec>
</root>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want to use `xsl:number` with an appropriate `format`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
 
  <xsl:param name="formats" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { '1' : 'I.', '2' : 'A.', '3' : '1.', '4' : 'a.', '5' : '(1)' }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="sec[@disp-level]/title/text()[1]">
      <xsl:variable name="number" as="xs:string">
          <xsl:number count="sec[@disp-level]" format="{$formats(current()/../../@disp-level)}"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s*\(?[A-Z0-9.]+\)?', $number)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrqt

That is XSLT 3 using an XPath 3.1 map to store the mapping from level number to level format but of course it could be modelled in an XML variable or a sequence in earlier versions of XSLT:

```
 <xsl:param name="formats" as="xs:string*"
    select="'I.', 'A.', '1.', 'a.', '(1)'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="sec[@disp-level]/title/text()[1]">
      <xsl:variable name="number" as="xs:string">
          <xsl:number count="sec[@disp-level]" format="{$formats[position() = current()/../../@disp-level]}"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s*\(?[A-Z0-9.]+\)?', $number)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I added more 'sec' with disp-level='4' at line no. 25 and ran the code but for this numbering does not change and rest of cases working fine see on LINK: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aixRuq/1

Comment: @Umaima, I think the regular expression for the `replace` call so far only looked for upper-case letters, you can change it to use `<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s*\(?[A-Z0-9.]+\)?', $number, 'i')"/>` so that `a.` will be replace by `$number` as well.

Comment: Hanon, Thanks and you are correct. I have a question what exactly work '<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>' in XSLT 3.0

Comment: It is a declarative way to set up the identity transformation as the base transformation , defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy to set up a built-in template that copies everything through, in a recursive manner so that any templates you add override the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

With [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) i made this:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m //title -v "named-content"  -o "," -v . -n input.xml
§15.1,§15.1  I.  WHEN PROCEEDINGS MAY BE INITIATED
,III. JURISDICTION AND VENUE
,A.   Trusts Under Continuing Court Jurisdiction
,A.   Pursuit of Claims
§15.2,§15.2  1.  Supervised Versus Unsupervised Trusts
§15.3,§15.3  3.  Removal From Continuing Court Jurisdiction
§15.3A,§15.3A a.  Mandatory Removal for Trust With Corporate Trustee
§15.3B,§15.3B 2.  Discretionary Removal for Trust With Individual Trustee
§15.35,§15.35 (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries
§15.35A,§15.35A    (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries (Added Section 5)
,VI.  LITIGATION INVOLVING TRUSTEE AND THIRD PARTIES
```

and the same on output.xml:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m //title -v "named-content"  -o "," -v . -n output.xml
§15.1,§15.1  I.  WHEN PROCEEDINGS MAY BE INITIATED
,II.  JURISDICTION AND VENUE
,A.   Trusts Under Continuing Court Jurisdiction
,B.   Pursuit of Claims
§15.2,§15.2  1.  Supervised Versus Unsupervised Trusts
§15.3,§15.3  2.  Removal From Continuing Court Jurisdiction
§15.3A,§15.3A a.  Mandatory Removal for Trust With Corporate Trustee
§15.3B,§15.3B b.  Discretionary Removal for Trust With Individual Trustee
§15.35,§15.35 (1) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries
§15.35A,§15.35A    (2) Consent or Affirmation by Beneficiaries (Added Section 5)
,III. LITIGATION INVOLVING TRUSTEE AND THIRD PARTIES
```

It is true, i see some differences between your input and output, but what the 'desired change' is, is unclear.

Comment: In the attached reference file input/output, We have marked the required change please once cross check and moreover Martin Honnen code is working fine also can visit the reference link as shared by Martin. Thank you!

Comment: @Martin Honnen - I added more 'sec' with disp-level='4' at line no. 25 and ran the code but for this numbering does not change and rest of cases working fine see on LINK: xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aixRuq/1

Comment: Please share your email id because i'm stuck one problem and cant explain on 'stackoverflow' code is lenthy